# Backup a Sql Server 2008 r2 transaction log clean file space:

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

Backup a Sql Server 2008 r2 transaction log cleans file space but not shrink it? Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Technically, backing up a transaction log in any version of SQL Server will mark as much space as possible as reusable, but will not shrink the file.  This is by design.  The file is designed to grow to a size required to log transactions between backups to avoid performance issues related to file growth events (among other things).  If you have issues with disk space, you need to take log backups more often, set it to SIMPLE mode (if appropriate for your recovery strategy), or increase disk space.

Shrinking the file, in most cases, is not best practice.

Comment: Thanks! That's was my thought too.